# Spring jpa @PreUpdate not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am facing the issue while updating the entity @preUpdate method not called.

but when I creating record it works properly by calling @prePersist method.

Spring boot - 2.1.4 Release

I tried with by creating different transaction still no luck and also if I do manually by setting the fields it will work like setMaskedDate(date);

here is my entity

```
@Table(name = "PROCESS_SUBJECT")
@Data
public class ProcessSubject {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)

    private String id;
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_DATE", nullable = true, length = 100, columnDefinition = "varchar(100)")

    private String encryptedSubjectDate;

    // Subject Date (Hack instead of Transient since Transient has issues 
        //with Updates)

    @Column(name = "SUBJ_DATE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date subjectDate;

    @Column(name = "MASKED_SUBJECT_DATE", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String maskedSubjectDate;
    public void setSubjectDate(Date subjectDate) {
        this.subjectDate = subjectDate;
        this.encryptedSubjectDate = null;
    }   

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.id = StringUtil.getRandomUUID();
        encrypt();
    }
    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        encrypt();
    }
    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad() {
        decrypt();
    }
    private void decrypt() {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(encryptedSubjectDate)) {
            String subjectDateStr = EncryptUtil.aesDecrypt(encryptedSubjectDate, this.id);
            try {
                this.subjectDate = DateUtil.getDate(subjectDateStr, DateUtil.Patterns.ISO_DATE);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                this.subjectDate = new Date();
            }
        }
    }
    private void encrypt() {
        if (subjectDate != null) {
            String dateStr = DateUtil.printDateStr(subjectDate, DateUtil.Patterns.ISO_DATE);
            this.encryptedSubjectDate = EncryptUtil.aesEncrypt(dateStr, this.id);
            this.maskedSubjectDate = DateUtil.printDateStr(subjectDate, DateUtil.Patterns.MM_DD);
        }}
}
```

here is a code inside a transaction

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void updateData(int id){
       Optional<Language> languageOpt =languageRepository.findById(id);
             if(languageOpt.isPresent()){
              ProcessSubject subject = languageOpt.get().getSubject();
                        subject.setSubjectDate(new Date());                    
                    processSubjectRepository.save(subject);
                  }}
```

I want to call the encrypt() method if an update happened to the entity.

Comment: You code looks okay. Do you see an UPDATE statement if you turn on sql logging?

Comment: in Update statement itself, it's coming as null. even I put debugger point on the @preupdate method, the method itself not executing

Comment: What is comming as null?